# Danger of damaging 13" macbook pro by charging it with 85w charger?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, charging, power, charger

We've got a range of laptops in our office all macbook pros some of which are 13" and some of which are 15".

The 15" laptops came with 85w chargers, and the 13" came with 60w chargers.

I want to buy some additiaonl chargers to leave plugged in around the office for anyone to use, but im unsure as to which type i should get.

- Would charging a 13" laptop on a 85w power supply damage it ?
- Would charging a 13" laptop on a 60w power supply damage it, or just make it slow at charging ?

Comment: How did this go?

Answer (score 5):

No.  You cannot damage a laptop by charging it with a charger rated more than what it originally came with.

When a *device* has a power requirement of 10W it means it will only ***draw*** up to 10W.  A power supply with a rating of 45W will supply up to 45W.<sup>1</sup>

A general rule of thumb is that you can always get a bigger power supply, never smaller.  Think of it like your electrical circuits in your house.  In the US, it's common to have 15A or 20A circuits.  Can you plug in vacuum cleaner that uses 12A?  Yup.  Can you run 2 at a time (24A) on the same circuit?  Nope, it will pop.  Can you run 1 vacuum and a 1A lightbulb (13A)?  Sure.

So, you can plug a device with a 60W draw into an 80W power supply, but it's not recommended to plug the same device with a 60W draw into a 45W power supply.

What can happen?

With the new USB-C ports on the Mac, most likely a slow charge.  With devices in general - you could damage/destroy the device and/or the power supply.

---

<sup>1</sup> This assumes the same voltage.  USB-C will auto negotiate the power delivery.  Older devices that don't do this; too many *volts* can fry your device.  More amps than necessary won't harm anything.   Also see:  [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: Thanks @allan so i shouldn't plug my 15" macbook pro (it came with an 85w  charger so i presume thats what it will draw) into a 13" macbook pro's 60w charger. Does magsafe 1 auto negociate what is required ?

Comment: You "can" plug it in, but I don't recommend it.  Magsafe includes a chip in the power connector that identifies itself to the power connector.  What may happen is a computer that powers, but doesn't charge (or vice versa).  Once someone borrowed my Magsafe adapter and replaced it with a lesser power one and I spent a week trying to figure out why my MB wouldn't charge and would only power up with a full charge.

Comment: I'd say this is half nitpick, half useful correction: Too many amps will *definitely* fry your device. Volts alone are harmless, but too high a voltage will induce a *current* that will fry things. So if a 60W device has an 85W charger, (provided proper current control is in place), it will just pull less amps and run at 60W. So really, too many volts *available* may fry your device, too many amps *available* might not.

Comment: @Allan, strange, I never knew that could happen. I've been charging a 15" macbook pro with a 60W charger for months and nothing bad happened.

Comment: @Rafael No offense, your first comment is totally wrong.  Volts are what fry electronics, since they travel farther than (e.g.) a resistor is made to resist, spreading electricity in amounts it's not supposed to be, and frying microcontrollers.  Also, the claim "too many amps will definitely fry your device" is also wrong.  For example, during brown-out the device is drawing more amps than it should, but does not fry.

Comment: @Alex, none taken. However I'm not sure you understand electricity very well. I have no idea of what you mean by 'voltage traveling further', as voltage is a measure of field strength; it does not move. High voltage *induces* high current, which causes resistive heating and thereby damages, which is sort of what you're saying. Technically it is current x TIME that damages, but the time component is implied (i.e. a high current for a microsecond isn't a problem). This seems to be a problem on the internet in general of people not understanding voltage vs. current.

Comment: Yes, I agree that Cur x Time can do damage via overheating.  However, applying even a small current with voltage higher than a microchip is designed for is able to fry that microchip.  For example, I have a battery charger that checks a battery's voltage by providing 1A with an increasingly higher voltage, until some condition is met.  So this chip, which is indended for charging a LiPo battery up to 5A (=18.5W) is only rated for 5V.  At one point the connection was bad, and the charger got up over 5V.  When the connection was finally made, the chip fried.  Maybe we should take this to a chat?