# Can I use a USB-C to Magsafe adapter to charge my MacBook Pro Unibody Mid 2012 15'' ? (85 W)

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, usb, charging, power

I saw this question [USB-C to MagSafe 2 Adapter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316400/usb-c-to-magsafe-2-adapter) but I'm not sure if it applies to my case that's why I ask

I found a converter from USB-C to Magsafe, but I read somewhere that there may be a power compatibility issue if the converter is used to charge an old MacBook Pro

My Computer is a MacBook Pro Unibody mid 2012, 15 inches, and needs 85 W of power

Could I order a USB-C charger with 85 W or higher, and just use a Magsafe converter to charge ?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I think 2012 Unibody MBPs have MagSafe 1 but, to be sure, you can look up the MagSafe type of your MBP in the "[Identify your Mac power adapter](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201700)" Apple support webpage.

Comment: @Alper It's in fact MagSafe 1, was unsure about it because I never really understood the difference between the different Magsafe types. Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: Not the same number of pins. On MagSafe 1 cable is parallel to MacBook so it can go to back or front; on MagSafe 2 the cable is perpendicular to MacBook, it goes to left.