# Which charger to get fast charging of iPhone XR?

Tags: iphone, charging

I'm about to buy an iPhone XR. Technical specification says it's possible to charge 50% of the battery in 30 minutes. However, seems that the provided 5W charger is not able to do that. I've been in the Apple Store and they said I need an iPad charger, but which one?

When a search for "charger" and filter for "XR model," I get [this one](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD836LL/A/apple-12w-usb-power-adapter). Is it the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked product is a 12 W adapter. To see the list of supported fast chargers for iPhone, refer to the Apple Support document:

- [Fast charge your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208137)

As mentioned in the article, to fast charge your iPhone, you'll at a minimum need a 18 W adapter. The same can be purchased from the Apple online store. You can also go with a compatible 3rd party adapter.

Comment: Are the 30, 61 or 87 W chargers faster than the 18 W for the IPhone?

Comment: @biotech Yes. More wattage equals faster charge.

Comment: @biotech No. Currently iPhone can be charge at max 18W.

Answer (score 3):

> However, seems that the provided 5 W charger is not able to do that
>   [charge the battery to 50% in 30 minutes]. I've been in the Apple
>   Store and they said I need an iPad charger, but which one?

You need a charger that outputs at least 18 watts or is rated for 5V at 3.6A (`W = V * A`)

However, (IMO) you should get a charger that's capable of powering/charging all (not simultaneously, obviously) your devices.  The way chargers work is that the rating 12W, 18W, 80W is the *maximum* amount of power that it will deliver not the amount of power it will "push" to the device.

So, if a device says it's rated at 18W, it will draw no more than that.  If your power supply is greater than or equal to 18W, it will work.  If it's less, it will either charge slowly or you could damage the power adapter.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/271794/119271) for more details

This is why you get a power adapter greater than what you need.  Getting an 80W, for example, will charge your MacBook Pro, your iPad, and you iPhone, whereas the 5W charger will only reliably charge your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this result you will need one of the adapters mentioned in the article:

> with accessory Apple USB-C Power Adapters (18W Model A1720, 29W Model A1540, 30W Model A1882, 61W Model A1718, 87W Model A1719).

([Source](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208137))

**NOTE** You might not be able to achieve the actual result:

> Charge time varies with environmental factors; actual results will vary.

There is no point getting a higher wattage adapter, if you don't need it for a Mac, as the highest output is 18 watts.

> The maximum power output is 18 watts and that seems enough to charge the iPhone 8 Plus and X at their maximum speeds, just like Apple's USB-C adapters.

([Source](https://www.macworld.com/article/3236904/ios/iphone-power-adapters.amp.html)),

You can get a higher wattage adapter but it will ruin battery life:

> And the myth that charging your device at a faster rate will reduce the life of your device's battery is false. For some older devices, the higher specced charger just won't work at all, while newer devices will just charge faster.

([Source](https://www.bobsbrain.com/blog/charging-101-how-do-amperage-voltage-wattage-affect-charging-devices?format=amp))

You can buy an 18 watt adapter from Apple [here.](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MU7T2LL/A/18w-usb-c-power-adapter)

Comment: @user3439894 edited

Comment: Whomever/wherever you sourced this material from, they have no idea about how chargers actually work.